# Python eval not working within a function

Tags: python, function, eval

I'm using [this](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) code to evaluate mathematical expressions from strings. And it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
from math import *

expression = raw_input()

# Math functions
safe_list = ['math', 'factorial', 'acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 'fmod', 'hypot', 'log', 'log10', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh'] 

# Create safe directory
safe_dict = dict([(key, locals().get(key, None)) for key in safe_list]) 
safe_dict['abs'] = abs

result = eval(expression, {"__builtins__": None}, safe_dict)
print result
```

I wrapped it in a function like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
from math import *

def calculate(expression):
    # Math functions
    safe_list = ['math', 'factorial', 'acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 'fmod', 'hypot', 'log', 'log10', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh'] 

    # Create safe directory
    safe_dict = dict([(key, locals().get(key, None)) for key in safe_list]) 
    safe_dict['abs'] = abs

    result = eval(expression, {"__builtins__": None}, safe_dict)
    if isinstance(result, float) and result.is_integer():
        result = int(result)
    print result

expr = raw_input()
calculate(expr)
```

And it still works for the basic operations, but none of the functions defined in `safe_dict` are working. `5**5` works with both programs, but `sin(pi)` worked with the first sample of code and it's not working with the second one. The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 20, in <module>
    calculate(expression)
  File "stack.py", line 14, in calculate
    result = eval(expression, {"__builtins__": None}, safe_dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please keep in mind: [Eval Really Is Dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).  You've set `__builtins__`, and you named your list `safe_list`, but you are not safe.  If you don't trust the input, don't use `eval`.

Comment: I'm aware `eval` is dangerous but I couldn't really think of any other way that would let me use Python math functions.

Comment: `ast` might get you there. http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html

Comment: Oh, that reminds me, I added a function that checks if the string to evaluate has `'[', ']', '_'` or `';'`. But I'll give `ast` a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it fails is that the functions you import from the math module are not local variables inside the function; they are global.  So when you read locals() and insert into the dict, it inserts None for every single one.  You would see this if you removed the `get(key, None)` and just accessed `locals()[key]` directly.

A better way is to use getattr on the math module.  Do `import math` (not `from math import *`) and then do `safe_dict = dict((k, getattr(math, k)) for k in safe_list)`.

Comment: +1 for reminding that use of `get` when there is no good way to handle the missing key is *not* a good idea.  (and obviously just returning `None` as the default in `get` is generally not solving any problems).

Answer (score 3):

Within your `calculate()` function, `locals()` does not include the functions imported from `math`. Therefore,  `safe_dict` is populated with a lot of `None`.

You could build up the `safe_dict` outside of `calculate()`, which would also have the advantage of performing better if you're making multiple calls to `calculate()`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I'll select BrenBarn's because it's more complete. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you have `'math'` in `safe_list`, and `math` is a module. To me,  it seems like `eval` is doing `math()`, which will cause it to choke the way it is doing.

Try removing `'math'` from `safe_list` and see if that helps at all.

On a side note: I'm not sure this is really the best way to do what you want to do. I think a design change is called for.

Comment: Actually, look at the other two answers. They both have some other suggestions as well