# Avoiding expensive calculations in Python IRC bot

Tags: python, calculator, arbitrary-precision

I'm using [this calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419463/python-eval-not-working-within-a-function) in a public IRC bot. Given that Python uses arbitrary precision by default, this would allow any user to execute something like `calc 10000**10000**10000` or `calc factorial(1000000)` and effectively "kill" the bot.

What I'd like to know is if there is some way of avoiding this. I've tried casting all the terms in the expression to float but `float(factorial(1000000)` still takes a long time to finish in the Python interpreter, and I'm not sure if a multithreading approach is the right way of doing this.

Comment: I know it uses `eval`, but I've tried to execute dangerous commands for a long time and I couldn't do anything. I know this doesn't guarantee that it's 100% safe but the users that will be using are "semi-trusted", meaning that they're not going to do weird stuff with `os` but I'm sure they will just kill the bot for fun.

Comment: Here's the actual code of the calculator, I used that one only for making the question briefer. http://pastebin.com/auF1krdh

Comment: Having no idea about python I suppose you need the approach like the one of Loic: Start the calculator as independent process and kill it after a specified time. I am afraid by using such functions as factorial it is nearly impossible to force the user to insert only fast computable input, there are simply too many ways to shoot your calculator in the foot.

Comment: @user1002327: See this link: [eval is really dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). You should use `ast.literal_eval` instead. Also, run your user input in a separate thread with a timeout. this will avoid problems from doing something like `factorial(1000000)`.

Comment: Heh, it feels like I've seen your comment somewhere else before. I've read that link and that's the reason I didn't let the user include any characters in the set `[]_;"'`. I'm hoping that makes  a lot harder to abuse `eval`. Oh, and the `eval` in my function is explicitly using `{"__builtins__": None}` instead of `{'__builtins__':{}}`, but I'm not sure if it makes a difference. Either way, I'll use `ast.literal_eval` and see what happens.

Comment: And I think I found a solution for this specific problem, so I'm writing an answer for it.

Comment: I forgot to include the complete code for the calculator, so here's the complete code: http://pastebin.com/GmigfMGS I think the `safe_dict` part _does_ make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `float()` cast was the solution after all.

First of all, the inverse trigonometric functions don't take values outside of their domain, so they're completely safe and the exception can be caught.

```
>>> acos(5e100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

The same thing happens with the `fmod()` function.

The "normal" trigonometric functions don't seem to have any problem with big values unless they're *really* big, which makes the function return `ValueError` again.

The rounding functions (`ceil()`, `floor()` and `round()`) work fine and return `inf` if the value is too big. The same goes for the `degrees()`, `log()`, `log10()`, `pow()`, `sqrt()`, `fabs()`, `hypot()` and `radians()` functions.

The hyperbolic trigonometric functions and the `exp()` function throw `OverflowError`s or return `inf`.

The `atan2()` function works perfectly fine with big values.

For simple arithmetic operations, the float cast makes the function throw an `OverflowError` (or an `inf`) instead of doing the calculation.

```
>>> float(10) ** float(100) ** float(100) ** float(1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
>>> float(5e500) * float(4e1000)
inf
```

Lastly, the problematic factorial() function. All I had to do was redefining the function in an iterative way and adding it to `safe_dict`.

```
import sys

def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    while (n > 0):
        fact = float(fact) * float(n)
        n -= float(1)
        if float(fact) > sys.float_info.max:
            return "Too big"
    return str(fact)

print factorial(50e500)
```

While this is a very ugly and grossly inefficient way of calculating a factorial, it's enough for my needs. In fact, I think I added a lot of unnecessary `float()`s.

Now I need to figure out how to put `float()`s around all the terms in an expression so this happens automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but I'd do it that way. Everything that you are going to run should be ran inside a different process. As far as I know, it's not possible to limit CPU usage or Memory usage of a single thread in a process.

That said, you have to create a new process which as with task to execute what the user entered and write it down to a file for exemple. You could do that with `fork`, create a new file using the `PID` and the main process will have to check until the child processes dies. Once the process dies, open the file "cool_calculator_[pid].out" and send it back to `IRC`.

Quite simple to do I guess.

Then using ulimit or other tools, you can limit the child process or even kill them using the master process. If the file with `pid` is empty just answer that there was an error or something. I guess you can even write some error like memory exceeded or cpu exceeded etc.

It all really depend on how you want to kill the bad processes.

In the end, your master process will have for job to spawn childs and kill them if needed and send back answers.

Comment: Oh well, since I get all kinds of errors in C for overflows, I'd like to know if detecting those overflows in Python is possible. As I said before, casting everything to float isn't enough, but it's fixing a lot of the problems. `float(10000) ** float(9999999999)` throws an `OverflowError` and so does `float(factorial(12000))` but for some reason `float(factorial(120000))` tries to complete the whole calculation.

Comment: `float(factorial(120000))` *does* throw an OverflowError, it just takes a while.  The OverflowError is occurring *after* the factorial is computed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't let it finish because I thought it would take much longer. Thanks for pointing that out.